# How to pass id of element into a directive with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is really basic and my first directive but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.  Here's my directive:

```
app.directive('rotateIcon', rotateIcon);

rotateIcon.$inject = ['$timeout'];

function rotateIcon() {
    return {
        link: function (event) {
            console.log(angular.element(event.target).attr('id'));
        }
    };
}
```

And my HTML snippet:

```
<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"
          id="wallet-refresh"
          ng-click="vm.setBalance();"
          rotate-icon></i>
```

How do I capture the id of my `<i>` as a variable inside of the directive?

Comment: go through the basics first https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive , you will get it.

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) linking function accepts 4 arguments, `scope, element, attrs, ctrl`, so in the 3rd argument you just have the id, or any other attribute the element has like this `attrs.id`

for example you can also give `rotate-icon` a value like `rotate-icon="val1"` and use it like `attrs.rotateIcon`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 scope: {
        id: '=',
    },
```

in directive

```
   app.directive('rotateIcon', rotateIcon);

    rotateIcon.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function rotateIcon() {
        return {
 scope: {
        id: '=',
       },
            link: function (element) {
                console.log(element.attr('id'));
            }
        };
    }
```

and your html tag :

```
<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"
          id="wallet-refresh"
          ng-click="vm.setBalance();"
          rotate-icon></i>
```

Comment: my friend, you are wrong in your answer since the `link` function does not accept event, perhaps you mean a click event? anyway in case you use the `scope: { id: '=' }` than you can just access from the scope like `link: function (scope) { console.log(scope.id); }`